# MobSF Android Activity APK Pentest

Tags: android, penetration-test, mobile, static-analysis, mobile-app

it is my first time with MobSF and Android APK assessment. I have found something while testing a specific APK and I am trying to understand the concept behind it:

Under HARDCODED_SECRETS in MobSF, was found a pair of KEY/SECRET related to the TWITTER SDK:

- com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_KEY" : "XXXXXX"
- com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_SECRET" : "XXXXXXX"

Under APK Activities list in MobSF, It was Found 2 activities related to TWITTER SDK:

- com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetcomposer.ComposerActivity
- com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity

When I tried to search in the JAVA SOURCE, I could find these variables (CONSUMER_KEY/CONSUMER_SECRET), but not the original extracted strings. So, I presume that they are byte-coded and MobSF is extracting real data somehow from the code.

So, my questions regarding this:

1. Where this information (key and secret pair) is being saved in my APK? It could being saved as bytecode?
2. What's the best approach to protect this information and avoid its exposure on a reverse code analysis? hide/obfuscate ??
3. What's the concept behind this? These 2 activities will be used by my APK to interact with Twitter and it will be using those hardcoded keys that MobSF discovered for that communication?
4. In terms of Android perspective, do I need to have a Twitter SDK or Twitter app installed in my Android System for this thing work? Or these Twitter's activities are already embedded in my APK? Putting in simple terms: activities from Twitter SDK present and used in my APK's code, require Twitter Mobile APP/SDK to be installed in the same Android system to work properly?

Thanks in advance.